How to use cmake with a completely unknown compiler?
I'm working with a completely new compiler for cmake with abnormal options. I'm confused about how to fully custom compiler rules for cmake.
I have known several rules such as CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT, CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE and so on. I have also known that CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_<LANG> can custom compiler include options, and CMAKE_<LANG>_DEFINE_FLAG can custom compiler marco define options. Even I have customed my own rules for simple C/C++ compiling and linking, and everything went well until I custom the Fortran preprocess rule : CMAKE_Fortran_PREPROCESS_SOURCE. The component <PREPROCESSED_SOURCE> by default uses a suffix "-pp.for" which is unacceptable for my compiler since the "-". How to custom this suffix?

I found just now that "-pp." was a hard-coded string in cmake-3.28.2\Source\cmNinjaTargetGenerator.cxx.  So I just used sed -b -i "s/\-\(pp\.\)/\.\1/g" cmake.exe to replace the character, which was a terrible solution in my mind.

"known" - what compiler exactly? How is it "unknown" - it is known to you. "And so on" - so on what exactly? What options did you set exactly to which values exactly, what is the full verbatim error nessage that you are getting. why is "-" unacceptable? what does it nean "unacceptable" - what or who doesn't accept it, in what way? What operating system are you using, what cmake generator are you using?

@KamilCuk: From my understanding the question is about a compiler for which CMake has no predefined scripts for configure. E.g., there is no well-known value for the variable CMAKE__COMPILER_ID. I don't think that actual compiler does matter for the given question. The question asks how to redefine a suffix for the file, preprocessed by Fortran compiler, and remove - from that suffix. Again, I don't think that actual error message from the compiler matters in that case.
